# Partial Application with Infix Functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying, partial-application, operator-sections

While I understand a little about  currying in the mathematical sense, partially
applying an  infix function was  a new concept  which I discovered  after diving
into the book [**Learn You a Haskell for Great Good**](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Given this function:

```
applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

The author uses it in a interesting way:

```
ghci> applyTwice (++ [0]) [1]  
[1,0,0]
ghci> applyTwice ([0] ++) [1]
[0,0,1]
```

Here I  can see  clearly that  the resulting  function had  different parameters
passed,  which would  not happen  by normal  means considering  it is  a curried
function (would it?). So, is there  any special treatment on infix sectioning by
Haskell? Is it generic to all infix functions?

---

*As a side note, this is my  first week with Haskell and functional programming,
and I'm still reading the book.*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can partially apply an infix operator by specifying either its left or right operand, just leaving the other one blank (exactly in the two examples you wrote).

So, `([0] ++)` is the same as `(++) [0]` or `\x -> [0] ++ x` (remember you can turn an infix operator into a standard function by means of parenthesis), while `(++ [0])` equals to `\x -> x ++ [0]`.

It is useful to know also the usage of backticks, (  `` ), that enable you to turn any standard function with two arguments in an infix operator:

```
Prelude> elem 2 [1,2,3]
True
Prelude> 2 `elem` [1,2,3] -- this is the same as before
True
Prelude> let f = (`elem` [1,2,3]) -- partial application, second operand
Prelude> f 1
True
Prelude> f 4
False
Prelude> let g = (1 `elem`) -- partial application, first operand
Prelude> g [1,2]
True
Prelude> g [2,3]
False
```

Comment: So, I don't know Haskell, but is `(1 \`elem\`)` the same as `elem 1`?

Comment: I like to think of `(++)` as a section where you omit both inputs.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, this is [the section syntax](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-300003.5) at work.

Sections are written as `( op e )` or `( e op )`, where op is a binary operator and e is an expression. Sections are a convenient syntax for partial application of binary operators.

The following identities hold:

```
(op e)  =   \ x -> x op e
(e op)  =   \ x -> e op x
```

Answer (score 5):

All infix operators can be used in sections in Haskell - except for `-` due to strangeness with unary negation.  This even includes non-infix functions converted to infix by use of backticks. You can even think of the formulation for making operators into normal functions as a double-sided section:

> `(x + y)` -> `(+ y)` -> `(+)`

Sections are (mostly, with some rare corner cases) treated as simple lambdas. `(/ 2)` is the same as:

> `\x -> (x / 2)`

and `(2 /)` is the same as `\x -> (2 / x)`, for an example with a non-commutative operator.

There's nothing deeply interesting theoretically going on here. It's just syntactic sugar for partial application of infix operators. It makes code a little bit prettier, often. (There are counterexamples, of course.)

Comment: Note that the "strangeness with unary negation" is due to the fact that it is ambiguous whether `(- 1)` should be interpreted as the numeric literal -1 or as the function `\x -> x - 1`. The choice of the creators of Haskell was to interpret it as a numeric literal, and provide the function `subtract`, which satisfies `subtract x = \y -> y - x`. They also provide `negate` which acts as the unary minus function, i.e. `negate x = -x`

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: Almost. `(- x)` translates to `negate x`, so `(- 1)` is `negate (fromInteger 1)`, not `fromInteger (-1)`. Of course, the two should be equivalent for well-behaved `Num` instances.

Comment: @hammar Ah ok, little bit of backwards logic there. Thanks for the correction!