# Function application in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, operators, partial-application, operator-sections

OK, it's been a long day and my brain may not function at Haskell level, but I just cannot understand one example from 'Learn You a Haskell'.

The section is called *Function Application with $*, and there is example of how `$` may be defined:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x = f x
```

So far everything is clear. I understand all examples in the section, except for the last one:

```
ghci> map ($ 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]
[7.0,30.0,9.0,1.7320508075688772]
```

Here we map `($ 3)` across list of functions and get result of application of those functions to `3`. But how is this possible?

From the first code snippet it's clear that first argument is a function, we can even write:

```
*Main> ($) sqrt 4
2.0
```

Now `($ 3)` is a partial application of function `$`, but `3` goes on function's position! So `3` is supposed to be a function or what?

There is another mystery: what the heck is `(4+)`? I know that `(+4)` is a partial application of function `+`, so `(4+)` should be partial application of function `4`? Nonsense. What sort of trick works here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partial Application with Infix Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131300/partial-application-with-infix-functions)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`($ 3)` and `(+ 4)` aren't partial applications - they're operator sections. A partial application would look like `(($) 3)` or `((+) 4)`.

An operator section of the form `(? x)` (where `?` stands for an arbitrary infix operator) binds the *right* operand of the operator, i.e. it is equivalent to `\y -> y ? x`. Likewise the operator section `(x ?)` binds the left operand and is thus equivalent to partial application.

Answer (score 9):

I think what's tripping you up is *operator sections*.  These let you partially apply an operator with either one of its arguments, so you can have the operators `(+4)` and `(4+)`, where `4` is the the second then the first argument to `+` respectively.  A more clear example might be `("Hello" ++)` versus `(++ "world")`, the former prepends `"Hello"` onto the front of a string, while the latter appends `"world"` onto the end of a string.

This is contrasted with using operators in prefix form with just parens around it.  In this form, the following are equivalent:

```
> let join = (++)
> join "Hello, " "world"
"Hello, world"
> (++) "Hello, " "world"
"Hello, world"
```

In prefix form, you treat the operator as a normal function and it accepts its first then second argument in order.  In operator sections, it matters which side of the operator the argument is on.

---

So in your example, you have the partial application of `($ 3)`, you can reduce it as

```
map ($ 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]
[($ 3) (4+), ($ 3) (10 *), ($ 3) (^ 2), ($ 3) sqrt]
[4 + 3, 10 * 3, 3 ^ 2, sqrt 3]
[7.0, 30.0, 9.0, 1.7320508075688772]
```

Comment: "you treat the operator as a normal function", I thought that 'operators' *are* normal functions in Haskell.

Comment: @Mark they're normal in every respect other than their syntax for application. They're by default infix, while a non operator function is by default prefix. When I say normal function, I mean a prefix function.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting confused with sections. A good way to grasp the concept of sections is playing with an example:

```
(<^>) :: Int -> Float -> Int
a <^> b = a
```

The above function is an useless function which returns the first parameter no matter what the second parameter is. But it accepts `Int` and then `Float` as input.

Now, because of sections you can apply with any one of their arguments:

```
λ> let a = (3 <^>)
λ> :t a
a :: Float -> Int
λ> let b = (<^> 3.0)
λ> :t b
b :: Int -> Int
```

See how the type of `a` and `b` are different because of sections.